# Google Carddav server returns 400 during initial sync request

Tags: carddav

While doing initial sync with Google's CardDav server I am doing a REPORT request with sync-collection method. In this request I am passing empty sync-token since its the initial sync.
This is as per RFC 6578 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6578#section-3.8).

The request body looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<D:sync-collection xmlns:D="DAV:">
<D:sync-token/>
<D:prop>
    <D:getetag/>
</D:prop>
</D:sync-collection>
```

I am expecting a Multi-Status response with etag's of all contacts.
However, google is returning HTTP error 400.

Can anybody if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: Does Google CardDAV support the sync collection REPORT?

Comment: Yes, as per this doc [Google Carddav API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/carddav/), it does.

Comment: OK. What URL do you hit? Also the page is a little weird, they say “after the first sync”, so maybe they do not support reports w/o a token.

Comment: I am hitting this URL: https://www.googleapis.com/carddav/v1/principals/userEmail/lists/default

Answer (score 0):

Your request is missing the sync-level element as per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6578#section-6.1

```
   <!ELEMENT sync-collection (sync-token, sync-level, limit?, prop)>
```

The Google API is not totally clear about whether they do support empty sync token.

> Client applications must switch to this mode of operation after the initial sync.

and

> Client programs use the sync-token PROPFIND request on the Address Book to obtain the sync-token representing its current state. Client applications must store this value and issue periodic sync-collection REPORT requests to determine changes since the last issued sync-token. Issued tokens are valid for 29 days, and the REPORT response will contain a new sync-token.

so it is well possible that they rejected the request for that reason.
If it is the case, one would do a PROPFIND with Depth:1 asking for the sync-token property as well as the getetag, then do a sync request based on the sync token property retrieved.

Comment: It does not make a difference by adding
`<D:sync-level>1</D:sync-level>`
to the request.
However, I think you are correct w.r.t. using PROPFIND for initial sync to get etags and sync-token.
But this is weird since empty sync-token approach works with both iCloud and Fastmail.

Comment: Well, as they say: "We have not implemented the full specification". And they mean it ;-/